# how to prevent bubbling event for overlapping elements?

Tags: javascript

i need a clue how to stop the #bubble flickering as soon as i move the mouse pointer above it, these two elements are placed on each other, the canvas' onMouseMove is obviously interfering with it, i use Chrome for testing.

```
<p id="bubble" onclick="noBubble();"></p>
<canvas id="kogal" width="450" height="630" onmousedown="onMouseDownkogal(this, event);" onmousemove="onMouseMoveKogal(this, event);" onmouseup="onMouseUpKogal();" onmouseout="onMouseOutKogal();">
```

is it possible to stop the onMouseMove for the canvas only when the mouse pointer is above the #bubble? i have tried preventDefault and return false in several combinations to no avail, thank you for any tips. ^_^

Comment: Since the elements are siblings, an event on the `p` element doesn't trigger an event on the `canvas` element and vice versa. If you are over the `p` element, `mousemove` should not be triggered on the `canvas` element. Proof: http://jsfiddle.net/2z2rbzzj/. Or maybe the `p` element is not on top of the `canvas`?

Comment: Im not qiet sure if i understand ur question but normaly u can stopp the bubbeling effect by writing "return false" or if you are using jquery: event.stopPropagation()

Answer (score 0):

`event.preventDefault()` just prevents default event behavior from happening, like a page reload when you submit a form. What you want is `event.stopPropagation()`, which will prevent an event from bubbling out to container elements.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Examples#Example_5:_Event_Propagation